# if $h^T D \psi = 0 \forall h \in \mathbb{R}^N$, then what can we say about $\psi$ and $D$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations, finance

$D$ is a $N \times M$ matrix. $h \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $\psi \in \mathbb{R}^M$

Would this mean that $\psi$ is in the Nullspace of $D^T$. because irrespective of h, $D$ is transforming these to $0$; which would happen only if $\psi$ is in the nullspace or $D = 0$?

What can we now say about the rows of D?

Comment: Could anyone please give me some information about this?

Comment: why don't you select $N$ linearly independent $\mathbf h$'s and see what happens?  if you collect these row vectors in a matrix $H$, you get $HD\psi = \mathbf 0$ and $H$ is invertible.